# Fresh Laravel Install - Blank page after installing breeze

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, breeze, inertiajs

Installed a fresh laravel 10 with no issues. I've made no edits and attempted to install the breeze starter kit, but am now getting a blank page. I've rebuilt from the ground up a few times so this does seem to be an out of the box issue. I'm developing using Sail on a MacBook Pro.

Getting this error in the developer console for the blank page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "define-data-property". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

This is corroborated with the fail I get when trying to compile assets with `npm run dev` locally, resulting in the following error:

```
LARAVEL v10.28.0  plugin v0.8.1

  ➜  APP_URL: http://localhost
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "define-data-property"

    node_modules/set-function-length/index.js:4:21:
      4 │ var define = require('define-data-property');
        ╵                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "define-data-property" as external to exclude it from
  the bundle, which will remove this error. You can also surround this "require"
  call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at run-time instead of
  bundle-time.
```

I've tried to understand why this would happen on a fresh install. I've looked for all the areas calling this particular package and it seems to be an issue with the Vite asset build. The node modules below are default, so I'm struggling to understand what's happening:

```
temp@temp-MacBook-Pro temp % grep -rl define-data-property
./node_modules/call-bind/CHANGELOG.md
./node_modules/set-function-length/CHANGELOG.md
./node_modules/set-function-length/index.js
./node_modules/set-function-length/package.json
./public/build/assets/DeleteUserForm-fe9fe383.js
./public/build/assets/VerifyEmail-903c3325.js
./public/build/assets/Login-83ade2f4.js
./public/build/assets/ConfirmPassword-34c099f2.js
./public/build/assets/Dashboard-8bc93fc9.js
./public/build/assets/UpdatePasswordForm-74474978.js
./public/build/assets/Edit-67e53f5e.js
./public/build/assets/ForgotPassword-9b85337d.js
./public/build/assets/ResetPassword-3f34808e.js
./public/build/assets/Welcome-c70472bd.js
./public/build/assets/UpdateProfileInformationForm-e6b9b180.js
./public/build/assets/Register-ff1f2716.js
./public/build/assets/app-516efd23.js
```

Appreciate any help!